# .map not working while looping object

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

[image: Demo]

I have above object called "list". and I wanted to use .map to loop and show inside my React Component and here is my attempt to do .

```
const {loading, city, list} = this.state;
    console.log(list);
    return loading === true
        ? <h1 className='header' > Loading.. </h1>
        : <div>
                <h2 className='forecast-header'>{city.name}</h2>
                <div className="forecast-body">
                    {
                        list.map((item) => (item.temp))
                    }
                </div>
          </div>
```

And it produced the error as below

> index_bundle.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: r.map is not a function

Can anyone explain me why it is happen? Thank you

Note: Below is how I initiate and update the state inside my component.

[image]

Comment: Seems like `list` is not an array at some point. You are loading the value from the component state. How are you initializing the state? How are you updating the state? At some point `list` is probably a plain object. Impossible to know 100% without are complete example though. But if it was an array you wouldn't get that error .

Comment: I have added additional information to my question .please take a look.@FelixKling

Comment: The initial value of `list` is an empty string. A string doesn't have a `.map` method. If `list` is supposed to be an array then you should initialize it as an empty array.

Comment: Does it matter that `list` gets logged as being an `array` before the `error` is fired? @FelixKling

Comment: @ArmanCharan: We haven't actually seen any evidence that this is the case (i.e. array logged before error).

Comment: I would set the default value of `loading` to `true` and insert a `return statement` for when `!Array.isArray(list)` @Achilles

Comment: humm ok let me try as you suggest @ArmanCharan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your initial state list is string. Change it for :

```
state={
forecastData: [],
loading: false,
city: '',
// CHANGE HERE
list: []
}
```

In this way when the component loads and there is no data the map function will work on an empty array rather than a string and throwing the error.

Comment: ahh it is not solving .. Here is my repo
https://github.com/HtunHtunHtet/weather-app/blob/master/app/components/Forecast.js

Comment: You dont need to update city, only list.
On your repo you update city: [].

This will fail as you are rendering

 <h2 className='forecast-header'>{city.name}</h2>

Comment: same error throwing in console @estebane97, error is "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Minified React error #31; "

Comment: Can you copy the console log for the response? You sure response has a list property? Looking into the response seems like the response is actually the list so you will need to do list: response

Comment: I am 110% sure there is a set of values in from response. I can't copy here because of the word limitation.

Comment: Ok, found the problem. The initial problem was solved with the solution I gave you. Now the second error is because the way you are rendering on your map function. You are trying to render x.temp, temp is an object and objects are not valid child components, So what you need to do is change your function to something like :

list.map((items) =>(items.temp.max))

Comment: You have max, min, norm, night, day and eve on that object, so display whatever you need

Comment: Ohhhh yAaaaa .. I found it .. thank you so so much .. you save my day

Answer (score 1):

```
// State.
state = {
  city: ''
  forecastData: {},
  list: [],
  loading: true
}

// Render.
render() {

  const {city, list, loading} = this.state

  // Loading.
  if (loading) return 'Loading ..'

  // Invalid List.
  if (!Array.isArray(list)) return 'Invalid list.'

  // Good To Go .
  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className='forecast-header'>{city.name}</h2>
      <div className="forecast-body">
        {list.length ? list.map(x => x.temp) : '..'}
      </div>
    </div>
  )

}
```